# Generic conforms to protocol and class (UITableViewCell)

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics, protocols

I want to make a generic Datasource class, therefor I want that the generic conforms to a UITableViewCell and the protocol ViewModel at the same time.

```
protocol ViewModel class {
    associatedtype T
    var viewModel: T { get set }
}


class TableViewDatasourceStandard<G: UITableViewCell>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource where G: ViewModel {
    let reUseIdentifier: String
    init( reUseIdentifier: String, cell: G) {
        self.reUseIdentifier = reUseIdentifier
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reUseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! G
        cell.viewModel
        return cell
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Value of type 'G' has no member 'viewModel'

I tried some different stuff but I can not get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
protocol ViewModel class {
  associatedtype T
  var viewModel: T { get set }
}
```

You should write

```
protocol ViewModel {
  associatedtype T
  var viewModel: T { get set }
}
```

Remove `class` and it will work as expected.

Comment: Why is this? What is the difference?

Comment: Because you write it with wrong syntax. Take a look at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html for protocol syntax

Comment: @trungduc, regarding [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20114880), you've approved it despite the edit breaking the code. Please be careful and avoid approving breaking changes. Thank you.